# How to print a manually defined struct in IDA pro while debugging?

Tags: ida, idapython

Lets say that i have manually defined a local struct while debugging in IDA pro, when i hover my mouse over any variable that is of that struct type, i can see its members.

Now if i have the variables's address, how to tell IDA to print every member of the struct on that variable in the output window? I am using windbg to debug kernel using IDA.

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @Benni Nope, even asked this question again and no one answered.. But if you are using windbg, you can still print windows based structs using dt command.